# Let $(A,+)$ be an abelian group of order $n\in\mathbb{N}$, it is [not so] clear then that $A$ is of exponent $n$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

My textbook reads (translated by me)

> Let $(A,+)$ be an abelian group of order $n\in\mathbb{N}$, it is clear then that $A$ is of exponent $n$.

Where $(A$ is of exponent $n)\iff$$(\forall a\in A,\; na=0)$.

---

This doesn't seem all that clear to me. I first considered the statement for the cyclic group $\langle a\rangle$ so that $b\in \langle a\rangle\implies \exists k\in \mathbb
{N},\; nb=n(ka)=k(na)=k0=0$. I concluded that the statement was true for cyclic groups. Is there a way of showing this for any finite group in an elementary "clear" (as the text suggests) way? I do not know about the Fundamental Theorem of Finite Groups yet (the quote is from the very beginning of the chapter).

*Edit:*
Note that, as the user lulu pointed out on [their answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4266807), the definition for "$A$ is of exponent $n$" used in this this question is a generalization of the standard definition ($n=\min\{m\in\mathbb{N}\mid \forall a\in A,\; ma=0\}$). Using the standard definition, the statement dos not hold true (counterexample on lulu's answer).

Comment: Which textbook are you referring to?

Comment: This follows from the Lagrange theorem.

Comment: @Shaun Elementos de Álgebra by Angel Pardo. The text is not available to the public (as far as I know) though, it belongs to my college.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, let $a\in A$. Then $|a|$ divides $|A|$. This is a standard property of finite groups. Hence, $n=k|a|$ for some $k\in \mathbb{N}$ and we conclude that

$$
na=k(|a|a)=k0=0,
$$
by definition of the order of an element.

Comment: (In case it wasn't clear enough) It is clear that $\langle a\rangle <A$. By Lagrange's theorem, $|A|=[A\colon \langle a\rangle]|\langle a \rangle |$ but $|a|=|\langle a \rangle |$ so $|a|$ divides |A|. The rest follows from the answer.

Answer (score 2):

This depends on your definition of exponent.

Many (most?) sources define the exponent of a finite group $G$ to be the *least* natural number $n$ such that $g^n=e$ for all $g\in G$.  Certainly, this is how I, personally, define the exponent of a group.  See [this](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Exponent_of_a_group) as another instance of this particular definition, you should easily be able to find more.

If that is your definition, then the claim is false.  The non-cyclic group of order $4$ has exponent $2$, for instance.

If, instead, you are defining "exponent" to be *any* natural number $n$ such such that $g^n=e$ for all $g\in G$, then the claim is true (since the order of any element must divide the order of the group).